# How do I make Terminal.app's scrollbars disappear in Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen, emacs

Once I upgraded to Lion, I found out that the vertical scrollbar is always plastered to the right side of the application window.

Because I run GNU Screen within Terminal.app, the right side of the `screen` session gets hidden partially underneath said scrollbar. Likewise for `emacs` sessions.

Is there a way to disable scrollbars in Terminal.app in Lion?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I assume you're not using a trackpad, and/or your **Show scroll bars** preference in System Preferences > General is set to either **Automatically based on input device** or **Always** (otherwise, you shouldn't be seeing persistent scrollbars).

Try changing this setting for Terminal only:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal AppleShowScrollBars -string WhenScrolling
```

Then close Terminal and reopen it for the change to take effect.

Comment: I am using a trackpad, but the setting worked perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: This didn't work for me in OS X 10.8.5, but [LionScrollbars](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70928/2767) did.

Comment: Great answer but the property name is case sensitive and the correct case is `AppleShowScrollBars`, making this change made the setting work.

Comment: m1h4 comment is correct about case. You also have to quit and relaunch terminal for the change to take affect. (Tested under El Capitan)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answers! Tested under Catalina also and need to quit and relaunch terminal for the change to take affect.

Answer (score 19):

System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars > When scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Try [LionScrollbars](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41429/lionscrollbars). It's the only thing that worked for me (besides setting the entire system to "When scrolling"). Works like a charm under 10.8.2.