# How do I permanently disable the scrollbar?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, macos

I set the Show Scroll Bars setting to "Automatically based on Mouse or Trackpad", but it constantly appears.

I do not want the scroll bar to automatically appear, or appear when scrolling. I want it to never appear. OS X provides the "Always" option, but I'm looking for a "Never" option.

How do I permanently disable the scrollbar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Terminal.app's scrollbars disappear in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20605/how-do-i-make-terminal-apps-scrollbars-disappear-in-lion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this application that claims to do what you asked for.

[The LionScrollbars](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41429/lionscrollbars)