# How to remove white side bar in terminal app?

Tags: terminal

On the right side of the terminal app appeared a white bar (I don't know how). This bar has a button which upon pressing splits the terminal horizontally. I would like to get rid of it, what must I do?

Comment: Did you plug in a new USB mouse/keyboard? In my case, that bar appeared on my terminal only when I had my mouse plugged in.

Comment: Indeed, they vanish upon unplugging the USB mouse. Crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars > When scrolling

[reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20605/how-do-i-make-terminal-apps-scrollbars-disappear-in-lion)

There is "terminal only" option as well